# Bubble sort for strings with structure

Tags: c

I tried using a bubble sort for strings that has to do with structures and arrays . Basically i want to compare the title of each book i put in alphabetical order. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
struct Book
{
    /* Book details */
    char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1];   
    char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1]; 
    int  year;                        
};
void menu_print_database(void)
{
    char temp[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1];
    char title[no_books][MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1];
    int i,sorted,swaps=0;
    int no_books;

    do
    {
        for (i=0; i<no_books; i++)
        {   
            if (strcmp(title[i-1], title[i]) > 0)
            {
                sorted=0;
                strcpy(temp, title[i+1]);
                strcpy(title[i-1], title[i]);
                strcpy(title[i], temp);
                swaps++;
            }   
        }
    } while (!sorted);

    for (i=0;i<no_books;i++){
        printf("Title: %s\n",book_array[i].title);
        printf("Author: %s\n",book_array[i].author);
        printf("Year: %d\n",book_array[i].year);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyone who sets `sorted` to anything other than `0` ?

Comment: just a hint: Implementing a sorting algorithm yourself for *educational purposes* is fine, but if you just need a means for sorting, that standard library already has you covered: [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)

Comment: In `menu_print_database`, `title` is not set, so how do you intend to sort it?

Comment: what does this do when `i` is 0?  `strcmp(title[i-1], title[i])`

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hint: the variable 'sorted' is only ever set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

1) The content of `title` isn't set but I suppose that you've only skipped that part of the code... Also, `char title[no_books][MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1];` uses a variable called `no_books`, which is only defined later.

2) Here, you're trying to access to `title[-1]` when `i==0`:

```
for (i=0; i<no_books; i++)
{   
    if (strcmp(title[i-1], title[i]) > 0)
```

3) `sorted` should be set to 1 before the for loop (you suppose that the array is sorted, if you enter in your if statement, you set `sorted` to 0).

4) the swapping is incorrect: `strcpy(temp, title[i+1])` should be `strcpy(temp, title[i-1])`

Comment: @MFisherKDX I've edited my answer. Do you see another error?